# C# System.UnauthorizedAccessException when using stream

Tags: c#

I am trying to upload some files to Google Drive via my C# programme. I am using stream to work with Google Drive API function to upload a file. But I have the exception called System.UnauthorizedAccessException. But when I use File.ReadAllText function I have not got the exception. Here's my code and exception is on line 7. Thank you for your answers.

```
public void uploadFile(string path, DriveService service)
{
    var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
    fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
    fileMetadata.MimeType = "txt";
    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
    using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "txt");
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.Upload();
    }

    var file = request.ResponseBody;
}
```

EDIT 1:

There is link to GitHub to full source code from my project: https://github.com/Nextesro/IDK-client

Comment: what's in `path`?

Comment: Please indicate the line throwing the error with a comment in the code instead of using line numbers, which SO doesn't have.

Comment: @Amy: It's this one: `using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO))`

Comment: @Danie A. White In path is "path" of file I want to upload.

Comment: Hm, is that third argument correct?  It looks like OP is using a namespace for the third argument, which expects a `FileShare` or `FileAccess` enumeration.

Comment: @PeterVeris That is obvious.  What does `path` literally contain?

Comment: @Amy Sorry I forgot to delete "System.IO" so it's only using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open)).

Comment: @Amy I tryed: C:\Users\Admin\file.txt

Comment: @PeterVeris Okay, that's a path on your local HD, so that should be fine.  Does the file exist at that path?  Do you have access to read it?

Comment: @Amy The file exists on that path and I can read it with System.IO.File.ReadAllText but not with stream.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`File.OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread) to open the file for read-only access.

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Considering that that method just returns `new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);`, and that the constructor OP is using defaults to `FileShare.Read`, I don't think this will solve anything.

Comment: @Amy In the OP. the third parameter is not specified which means that `FileAccess.ReadWrite` will be used, also requesting write access to the file.

Comment: You're right, I just noticed I was looking at the wrong constructor overload.  The `FileAccess` depends on the `FileMode` (Append -> Write, anything else is ReadWrite).

Comment: @NineBerry when I use using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path)) it still gives me the exception.

Comment: @PeterVeris But when you use `File.ReadAllText()` in the same application run by the same user (which is that by the way?), then it works? That is hard to believe.

Comment: I agree, that is not believable.  There is something you aren't telling and showing us.

Comment: Tomorrow I Will put my source to github and I will type here link.

Comment: Your code has `uploadFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialogUpload.FileName)`. And you use that variable which only contains the directory, not the file name.